# How to share pictures saved in IsolateStorageFile on Facebook using Windows Phone Silverlight?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, silverlight-5.0

I want to know how to implement the sharing of images on Facebook, images are saved both nell'IsolateStorageFile that in the phone gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `ShareMediaTask` on sharing the image?

Could follow this reference for more guidance:

[How to use the share media task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207027(v=vs.105).aspx)